# How do I mount my NAS?

Tags: mount, fstab

I just got a Raspberry Pi 3 and I am currently trying to mount my WD MyCloud EX2 to it and I am not having any luck.

I tried following this guide I found [here](https://alextheedom.wordpress.com/raspberry-pi/connect-to-a-nas-drive/)

But I got this error: `unable to find suitable address`.

I attempted to edit the `/etc/fstab` file to this

```
192.168.1.119/WDMyCloudEX2/PiDownloads /home/ddrossi93/myNAS/myShare nfs 
workgroup=WORKGROUP,users,auto,user_xattr 0 0,username=admin,password=pw
```

and I now get the error: `remote share not in 'host:dir' format`.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong and could use some guidance.

EDIT: I got it to work, I had to turn on NFS access on my NAS

Comment: Seeing as you found the solution could you please make it an answer and mark it as correct.

Comment: I've just resolved a similar issue, so in the hope that it's helpful for future visitors, a note (since the formatting on neither of the question or the answers makes this clear):

The columns of `/etc/fstab` entries must be separated by TABs, not spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing what I listed in the description, I then found an option in the settings of the WD myCloud NAS to turn on NFS access. Once this was enabled, it mounted without any errors or issues.

Answer (score 0):

You should have `//` before `192.168.1.119`. `fs_mntops` should be before `fs_freq`.

```
//192.168.1.119/WDMyCloudEX2/PiDownloads /home/ddrossi93/myNAS/myShare nfs workgroup=WORKGROUP,users,auto,user_xattr,username=admin,password=pw 0 0
```

Refer to the man page for fstab (5) for what `fs_mntops` and `fs_freq` are.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the response. I am not sure what you mean by fs_mntops and fs_freq

Comment: nevermind I got it to work. I had to turn on NFS Access on my NAS. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are right deciding to do it using fstab. I own a raspberry pi 1 and the same NAS as you. This is my fstab file content (for each network drive write a line):

`//192.168.1.15/afolder /media/MyNAS/afolder cifs uid=myuser,credentials=/home/myuser/.MyNAS-credentials 0 0`

As you can see, I store credentials in a separate file (/home/myuser/.MyNAS-credentials), which contains the following:

```
username=username
password=passwd
domain=WORKGROUP
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. I am still having some trouble. I am getting a parse error on the same line for the code I am posting. I am also getting this error as well, "mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified"

Comment: nevermind I got it to work. I had to turn on NFS Access on my NAS. Thanks!

Comment: @Ddrossi93 could you thumbs up my answer and mark it as a correct answer, please?